# Tailor a result from ES6 array filtering

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, filter

I have an array that looks like this:

userData:

```
[
{firstName:"sally", lastName:"yates", id:1},
{firstName:"bob", lastName:"ross", id:2}
]
```

petData:

```
[
{pet:"dog", ownerId:1}
{pet:"cat", ownerId:2}
]
```

And I want my result to look like this:

```
[
{pet:"dog", userId:1, userName:"sally yates"},
{pet:"cat", userId:2, userName:"bob ross"}
]
```

I can perform the filter but only for 1 name. What would be the appropriate way to get both first and last names?

```
 petData.forEach(function(item) {
    var creator = _.pluck(
    _.filter(userData, {
    id: item.ownerId
    }),
    "first_name"
    );
    item["userName"] = creator;
  }
```

**Sorry One point is I have to keep the forEach function since other dev's code uses it for other conditionals

Comment: petData is missing a comma

Comment: btw, what should happen, if a user does not has a per, or more or a pet has a not known user?

Comment: @NinaScholz it guaranteed that every pet has a user, but not the other way around

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve expected result, use below option of using map and filter

1. Loop petData using map
2. FIlter the userData array with petData ownerId

```js
let userData = [
{firstName:"sally", lastName:"yates", id:1},
{firstName:"bob", lastName:"ross", id:2}
]

let petData = [
{pet:"dog", ownerId:1},
{pet:"cat", ownerId:2}
]

console.log(petData.map(v => {
  let user = userData.filter(val => val.id === v.ownerId)[0]
  v["userName"] = user.firstName + ' ' + user.lastName;
  v["userId"] = v.ownerId;
  delete v.ownerId;
  return v
}))
```

**Option 2:** Using forEach as requested in question

```js
let userData = [
{firstName:"sally", lastName:"yates", id:1},
{firstName:"bob", lastName:"ross", id:2}
]

let petData = [
{pet:"dog", ownerId:1},
{pet:"cat", ownerId:2}
]

let result =[]
petData.forEach(v => {
  let user = userData.filter(val => val.id === v.ownerId)[0]
  v["userName"] = user.firstName + ' ' + user.lastName;
  v["userId"] = v.ownerId;
  delete v.ownerId;
  result.push(v)
})
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd create a Map of Users by id:

```
  const byID = new Map();

  for(const user of userData)
    byID.set(user.id, user);
```

Now you can easily look up the pets owner and merge its name:

```
 for(const pet of petData) {
   const owner = byID.get(pet.ownerId);
   pet.userName = owner.firstName + " " + owner.lastName;
   pet.userId = owner.id;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could move the users into a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and map all pets.

```js
const getName = ({ firstName, lastName } = {}) => [firstName, lastName].join(' ');

var userData = [{ firstName: "sally", lastName: "yates", id: 1 }, { firstName: "bob", lastName: "ross", id: 2 }],
    petData = [{ pet: "dog", ownerId: 1 }, { pet: "cat", ownerId: 2 }],
    users = new Map(userData.map(o => [o.id, o])),
    result = petData.map(({ pet, ownerId: userId }) => ({ pet, userId, userName: getName(users.get(userId)) }));
    
console.log(result);
```

Comment: No need to concatenate strings on ES6 like that, can be `\`${o.firstName} ${o.lastName}\``

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the array of `pets` and inside each iteration of the `map`, use [Array.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to get the related `person` object from the other array:

```js
const persons = [
  {firstName:"sally", lastName:"yates", id:1},
  {firstName:"bob", lastName:"ross", id:2}
];

const pets = [
  {pet:"dog", ownerId:1},
  {pet:"cat", ownerId:2}
];

let res = pets.map(({pet, ownerId}) =>
{
    let {firstName, lastName} = persons.find(({id}) => id === ownerId);
    return {pet, userId: ownerId, userName: `${firstName} ${lastName}`};
});

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

And here is another tricky version using [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```js
const persons = [
  {firstName:"sally", lastName:"yates", id:1},
  {firstName:"bob", lastName:"ross", id:2}
];

const pets = [
  {pet:"dog", ownerId:1},
  {pet:"cat", ownerId:2}
];

let res = Object.values([...persons, ...pets].reduce((acc, {id, ownerId, pet, firstName, lastName}) =>
{
    let userId = id === undefined ? ownerId : id;
    let userName = `${firstName} ${lastName}`;
    acc[userId] = acc[userId] || {};
    Object.assign(acc[userId], {userId}, (id === undefined ? {pet} : {userName}));
    return acc;
}, {}));

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not really care about the order of the keys you can use an `object literal` for the users and then just get the user by `key/ownerId` for the final result:

```js
let users = [{ firstName: "sally", lastName: "yates", id: 1 }, { firstName: "bob", lastName: "ross", id: 2 } ]
let pets = [ {pet:"dog", ownerId:1}, {pet:"cat", ownerId:2} ]

let usersMap = {}; users.forEach(u => usersMap[u.id] = u)
let result = pets.map(({pet, ownerId}) => ({ pet, userId: ownerId, username: `${usersMap[ownerId].firstName} ${usersMap[ownerId].lastName}` }))

console.log(result)
```

This approach would be more performant than doing a filter on each pet iteration etc.